# Flexslider w/thumbnail controlNav - not syncing

Tags: flexslider

I've been going mad trying to find what I'm doing wrong here. To the point where I've just set up a test html page, with the EXACT code and images from the demo page
http://flexslider.woothemes.com/thumbnail-controlnav.html

```
<body>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="flexslider.css" type="text/css">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.flexslider.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

// Can also be used with $(document).ready()
$(window).load(function() {
  $('.flexslider').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    controlNav: "thumbnails"
  });
});

</script>

</head>
<div class="flexslider">
    <ul class="slides">
         <li data-thumb="slide1-thumb.jpg">
          <img src="slide1.jpg" />
        </li>
        <li data-thumb="slide2-thumb.jpg">
          <img src="slide2.jpg" />
        </li>
        <li data-thumb="slide3-thumb.jpg">
          <img src="slide3.jpg" />
        </li>
        <li data-thumb="slide4-thumb.jpg">
          <img src="slide4.jpg" />
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</body>
```

It looks as if everything is fine apart from the fact that in my 4 image gallery, the Flexslider is highlighting thumbnail 1 and displaying image 4, then highlighting thumbnail 2 and displaying image 1 etc.

thumbnail 1 displays image 4
thumbnail 2 displays image 1
thumbnail 3 displays image 2
thumbnail 4 displays image 3
then it loops around.

Does anyone have any idea?

Please save my head!

[Demo of above code](http://stevearscott.com/test/test.html)

Comment: It appears it is a problem with Flexslider 2.2.2, version 2.2.1 works fine! Man, this was driving me nuts!

Answer (score 1):

This issue happens to me. When I checked my downloaded files (woothemes-FlexSlider-version-2.2.2-0-gce5441b) I noticed that the demo page (thumbnail-controlnav.html) shows incorrect order of images. What I did, I compare it to the live site http://flexslider.woothemes.com/thumbnail-controlnav.html and update my copy of the script jquery.flexslider.js then it works fine!